# Xamarin Forms WithParentActivityOrWindow not working if lauched from a link

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal, android-app-links

I'm doing a Xamarin Forms application and have all wired to integrate with `MSAL.net`. In Android, when I launch the application from the drawer, everything works fine, the authentication it's done and the 
`MainActivity.OnActivityResult` it's called (it's where I have       `AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(a_RequestCode, a_ResultCode, a_Data))`.

This application can be launched also from an AppLink but when I launch the application this way, then after the authentication it's done, the `MainActivity.OnActivityResult` isn't called and an empty form with just the title of the application it's shown.

I'm using as `WithParentActivityOrWindow` parameter the `MainActivity`. Any idea why using the link method doesn't work?

Thanks

EDIT: This is how my MainActivity looks like:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
AutoVerify = true, Categories = new[]
{
  Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
  Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
},
  DataScheme = "https", DataPathPrefix = "/",
  DataHost = "MyApp.com"
)]

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
private App _App;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  // TODO: If not shell remove this?
  TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
  ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental", 
    "FastRenderers_Experimental");
  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

  AnimationViewRenderer.Init();

  UserDialogs.Init(() => this);

  Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

  Plugin.InputKit.Platforms.Droid.Config.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

  FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);

  CarouselViewRenderer.Init();

  // Exception handler
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
  TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
  AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironmentOnUnhandledException;

  // Pass the activity to be used as OAuth return 
  _App = new App(this);
  LoadApplication(_App);
}

private void AndroidEnvironmentOnUnhandledException(object a_Sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs a_Args)
{
  //a_Args.Handled = await _App.ShowUnhandledExceptionAsync(a_Sender, a_Args.Exception);
}

private void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object a_Sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs a_Args)
{
  _App.ShowUnhandledExceptionAsync(a_Sender, a_Args.Exception);
}

private void OnUnhandledException(object a_Sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs a_Exception)
{
  //_App.ShowUnhandledExceptionAsync(a_Sender, a_Exception.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions,
  [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); 
  base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

public override void OnBackPressed()
{
  if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Count > 0)
  {
    Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed);
  }
  else
  {
    base.OnBackPressed();
  }
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int a_RequestCode, Result a_ResultCode, [CanBeNull] Intent a_Data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(a_RequestCode, a_ResultCode, a_Data);
  AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(a_RequestCode, a_ResultCode, a_Data);

  MultiMediaService.SharedInstance.OnActivityResult(a_RequestCode, a_ResultCode, a_Data);
}
```

Comment: You could override the method `OnNewIntent` to check if the app can receive the callback when been launched by the link. And you would better post the full code in MainActivity to check the issue better .

Comment: I have added my MainActivity. Also found there it is a bug filled at [Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1508)

Comment: OK , we will focus on it .